# Prevent site zoom with two fingers ios

Tags: javascript, html, ios, viewport

How to prevent a user in iOS from zooming a site with two fingers?

I put this attribute

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

it only works with double click, and when zooming with two fingers it does not work, how to solve this or ios will let you zoom in anyway?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the information above to the viewport meta tag did not work for me either. I added

```
body {
  touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
}
```

and everything works perfectly on Android. However, we're using ant design and for some reason, there's a class called ant-scrolling-effect being added to the body that adds

```
body {
  touch-action: none;
}
```

but it still lets you zoom on iOS. I have not figured out why this works perfectly on Android, but does not work on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Use the touch-action property.

To disable pinch/zoom gestures and double tap to zoom gestures:

```
body {
  touch-action: pan-x pan-y;
}
```

If you don't need panning gestures either, just do:

```
body {
  touch-action: none;
}
```